# Has anyone built a paragliding simulator?

Tags: flight-simulator, paraglider

I am searching for a manual on how to build a paragliding simulator, where you can practice controlling the paraglider. My idea of the project is that you sit in a paraglider seat and you can experience the behaviour of the seat in a flight.

If you have any references to already built projects, it would be awesome.

Comment: You mean this sort of thing? http://xcmag.com/news/new-paraglider-flight-simulator/

Comment: Ubisoft released "Steep", a mountain sports game that include paragliding. But it wasn't realistic at all and disappointing IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popular [simulator X-Plane](https://www.x-plane.com/) allows you to [build your own aircraft models](https://developer.x-plane.com/manuals/planemaker/) it looks like [some people have built paraglider models](https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/4486-paraglider-project/) that you may want to take a look at. As for controls you can build [all kinds of custom interfaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5BmA3ejyHY) to simulate the controls of a paraglider but it will take some work.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you may add that custom output interfaces would need to be employed, in order to experience the behavior of the seat. (Tilting the seat, and the image, etc).

Comment: Hey Dave thank your very much for your good suggestion. Do you know somehting about an real life steering seat. Like what they build here, I am searching right now for similar projects like this: http://www.usppa.org/schools-training/initial-training-for-new-paramotor-pilots/powered-paragliding-simulator/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an operational paragliding simulator (located in Amsterdam, Netherlands) that may serve as an example: https://flightcoach.nl/en/services/vrsim/
It did not yet exist when the question was asked.

Comment: Welcome to AvSE!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The game **[Paragliding Sim](https://evan-burrows.itch.io/paragliding-sim)** is currently on version 4.1. It is available on Windows, Linux and Mac.

> The most realistic paragliding sim ever made!
>
> The wings are softbody, meaning they can flex and twist!
>
> Fly cross coutry, ridge soar or speed fly the terrain with any glider
> of your choice. This simulator includes dynamic wind (ridge lift, lee
> side rotor) as well as thermals which are most likely found on the
> sunny faces of the terrain.
>
> Recently updated with anabatic (sunny slope) winds!
>
> Now has paramotors!
>
> In the future I plan to add:
>
> - Hang Gliders
> - Fixed Wing Aircraft

Comment: The stated question isn't about a simulator on a computer screen, but using actual hardware; I don't believe this post actually answers the question *as asked*.

Comment: Fair enough. But I think it would be better than the alternatives if you build a hardware to go with it.